# How to make netcat try to connect to host until response in windows

Tags: netcat

Hello I am new to the forum so sorry if i am not very precise. My question is : is it possible to make netcat try again and again to connect to a host until it gets a response in windows?
Exemple : nc - (option to retry connection until response) 1234
Thanx in advance

Comment: You probably need a script to call it repeatedly (i.e. doubt they built that functionality into netcat)

Comment: Ok cheers thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone in the future here is a vbs script to relaunch netcat after certain period of time. This script will wait 10 seconds before launching netcat in background then will relaunch it every 5 s :

dim waittime :waittime = 10000
do

Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run """C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\test\nc localhost 1234""", 0 , false

WScript.Sleep 5000

oShell.Run "taskkill /im cmd.exe", , True

WScript.Sleep(waittime)
loop